# Setting up Cygwin + Android NDK + cocos2Dx to work with Eclipse

Tags: android-ndk, cygwin, cocos2d-x

**I'm following a tutorial from this website:** [Monetizing Game Apps by Todd Perkins](http://www.lynda.com/Android-tutorials/Understanding-downloading-Cocos2d-x/107169/126919-4.html)

*Access to all the files are not required for the questions I'm asking. I have done research on how to solve this on stack overflow and discussed it below*

I have followed the tutorial and it has asked me to:

1. Install Cygwin
2. Download Cocos2dx-2.0.1(I know this is old, but I don't want to deal with deprecating problems until I'm more confident with the environment)
3. Run create-android-project.bat(works fine).
4. Open project I created- and move to proj.android and run build_native.sh in Cygwin.
5. Then I open up cygwin.bat, navigate to myproject/proj.android and run ./build_native.sh

**Problem:**

$ ./build_native.sh
Using prebuilt externals 
./build_native.sh: line 74: /cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r9c-windows-x86_64/ndk-build: No such file or directory

So I looked into the files and double-checked my changes:

1. In create-android-project.bat I modified the following variables:

   set _CYGBIN=c:\Cygwin64\bin

set _ANDROIDTOOLS=c:\Program Files (x86)\ADT\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\sdk\tools

set _NDKROOT=c:\android-ndk-r9c-windows-x86_64

1. Check line 74 that cygwin complained about in myproject/proj.android/build_native.sh:

`echo "Using prebuilt externals"
$NDK_ROOT/ndk-build -C $GAME_ANDROID_ROOT \
    NDK_MODULE_PATH=${COCOS2DX_ROOT}:${COCOS2DX_ROOT}/cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt`

1. Double check what NDK_ROOT is pointing to in build_native.sh:

   NDK_ROOT=/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r9c-windows-x86_64
   COCOS2DX_ROOT=/cygdrive/c/Users/DarkRaveDev/Documents/cocos2d-x-2.0.1
   GAME_ROOT=$COCOS2DX_ROOT/chaara
   GAME_ANDROID_ROOT=$GAME_ROOT/proj.android
   RESOURCE_ROOT=$GAME_ROOT/Resources

**My Research:**

I surfed SO for quite some time and tried the following from SO:

1. EOL Conversion in Notepad++ so LF works for windows for the build_native.sh
2. An answer somewhere said I need to install the make package when installing cygwin.. I'm not getting this problem, so I'm not sure if this applies.
3. I have searched many ways to set path - NDK_ROOT

**QUESTION:**

What exactly am I doing wrong? Is it the variables are badly set or is cygwin not properly installed?

Comment: Did you get the same version of the NDK as in your tutorial? Looks like that was written for `r8` and your using `r9`.

Comment: give your NDK_Path in the build native.sh      like this   NDK_ROOT="D:\android-ndk-r8d"

Comment: @Elliot: I don't have the same version now that I think about it!

@ Singhak: I don't quite understand what you're asking me to do. Also I have a single partition currently.

For anyone else reading this. Cygwin install asks for specific packages. I've read on SO that you need to install the DEVEL package (Easier to do all) -

Comment: Not a solution to your problem but I would recommend putting ADT in a directory without spaces. In my experience, using space in paths cause all kinds of problems in NDK development.

Comment: Check out tutorial here: http://patidarvikas.blogspot.in/2013/09/build-and-run-cocos2dx-android-project.html

Comment: @darkravedev i am saying that set your NDK_ROOt in build_native.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Thank you to everyone who commented! :)**

This is what I ended up doing.

1. **Reinstall Cygwin** : When you get to the select packages to install page, make sure to find **DEVEL** and change the install action from default to install. I know its a lot of megs but it's easier than combing through it. If you do want to comb through it and get only what you need, I suggest using this website: [Installing a c++ compiler for windows](http://cs.calvin.edu/curriculum/cs/112/resources/installingEclipse/cygwin/)
2. **Make your paths simple** : Like user2359247 suggested.
3. Finally run the create_android.bat, open your android project. Keep the path location of your build_native.sh file in mind and open your cygwin terminal.
4. Navigate to the path in cygwin, and run the file with sh build_native.sh: At this point everything was quite smooth sailing.

NOTE:

**Also I kept using my version of ndk which is r9 instead of r8 in the tutorial, it didn't give me any hiccups.**

Thank you SO!