# Cocos2dx is not creating a project

Tags: android, cygwin, cocos2d-x

i have tried, I don't understand why cocos2dx not creating android project it's giving that

**Error! Don’t run in cygwin. You should run corresponding bat.**

That's my bath file code:

```
@echo off
:: This script is used to create an android project.
:: You should modify _ANDROIDTOOLS _CYGBIN _NDKROOT to work under your environment.
:: Don't change it until you know what you do.

setlocal

:: Check if it was run under cocos2d-x root
if not exist "%cd%\create-android-project.bat" echo Error!!! You should run it under cocos2dx root & pause & exit 2 

if not exist "%~dpn0.sh" echo Script "%~dpn0.sh" not found & pause & exit 3

:: modify it to work under your environment  
set _CYGBIN=c:\cygwin64\bin
if not exist "%_CYGBIN%" echo Couldn't find Cygwin at "%_CYGBIN%" & pause & exit 4

:: modify it to work under your environment
set _ANDROIDTOOLS=c:\Program Files (x86)\android\android-sdk\tools
if not exist "%_ANDROIDTOOLS%" echo Couldn't find android sdk tools at "%_ANDROIDTOOLS%" & pause & exit 5

:: modify it to work under your environment
set _NDKROOT=c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-ndk-r8b
if not exist "%_NDKROOT%" echo Couldn't find ndk at "%_NDKROOT%" & pause & exit 6

:: create android project
set /P _PACKAGEPATH=Please enter your package path. For example: org.cocos2dx.example:
set /P _PROJECTNAME=Please enter your project name:
if exist "%CD%\%_PROJECTNAME%" echo "%_PROJECTNAME%" exists, please use another name & pause & exit 7
echo "Now cocos2d-x suppurts Android 2.1-update1, 2.2, 2.3 & 3.0"
echo "Other versions have not tested."
call "%_ANDROIDTOOLS%\android.bat" list targets
set /P _TARGETID=Please input target id:
set _PROJECTDIR=%CD%\%_PROJECTNAME%

echo Create android project
mkdir %_PROJECTDIR%
echo Create Android project inside proj.android
call "%_ANDROIDTOOLS%\android.bat" create project -n %_PROJECTNAME% -t %_TARGETID% -k %_PACKAGEPATH% -a %_PROJECTNAME% -p %_PROJECTDIR%\proj.android

:: Resolve ___.sh to /cygdrive based *nix path and store in %_CYGSCRIPT%
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('%_CYGBIN%\cygpath.exe "%~dpn0.sh"') do set _CYGSCRIPT=%%A

:: Resolve current dir to cygwin path
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('%_CYGBIN%\cygpath.exe "%cd%"') do set _CURRENTDIR=%%A

:: Resolve ndk dir to cygwin path
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('%_CYGBIN%\cygpath.exe "%_NDKROOT%"') do set _NDKROOT=%%A

:: Throw away temporary env vars and invoke script, passing any args that were passed to us
endlocal & %_CYGBIN%\bash --login "%_CYGSCRIPT%" %_CURRENTDIR% %_PROJECTNAME% %_NDKROOT% %_PACKAGEPATH% "windows"

pause
```

and when i run bath make project it's give error like as:
http://postimg.org/image/oihy9ovyf/79a6c589/

That's screen shots.

Please let me know how i can fix it

Comment: maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/21004174/201863

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Thanks for your response let me try to re install it then i will let you know it's still here or not

Comment: also, google the exact error message and you'll find some tips like not having spaces in the path

Comment: @LearnCocos2D yeah i searched about that but no one give good suggestion about that how i can write space batch file. if you know about that so please let me know

Comment: what about just removing spaces from the path? You only need to rename the folders in windows, for instance create the project in C:\MyProject

Comment: @LearnCocos2D actually buddy confusion is that i intall sdk in program file (x86) if i change its folder dose it make any problem or not?